# Regex for a youtube video (iframe)

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a **html text** and i want to **extract the "src" from the iframe**.

i have this example here:
this works, it selects exactly what i want... but when i put the REGEX on my code it says: "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /**" 
 http://www.regexr.com/3b4rg

**code:**

```js
    strInputCode='<p><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v=k4ixAfJ1LuI?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="560"></iframe></p> ';


var m,
            urls = [],
            str = strInputCode,
            rex = /<iframe[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?[^>]*\></iframe>/g;

    while (m = rex.exec(str)) {
        urls.push(m[1]);
    }
      
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
          
        console.log("---------------",urls[i]);
    }
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Change `/iframe` to `\/iframe`

Comment: You're missing the escape sequence for `/` in `</iframe>` .